# Why header of table changes background color if tr:nth-child(odd) is set?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Setting background colors for header odd/even rows of table in tailwindcss: 2.2  app I use css like :

```
.editor_listing_table_header {
    @apply bg-gray-700 admin_block_border border-t-2 border-b-2;
}


/*
.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #10eef9; 
}
*/

.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(even) {
    /*background-color: #e8e8e8; !* light; *!*/
    background-color: #f1f1f1; /* 0aaf7e Green; */
}
```

as result 1st row(and all odd rows) have background color of the page - as css for it is commented above.

If to uncomment row :

```
.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #10eef9;
}
```

Then 1st row(and all odd rows) have background color I need, but header also has this color and that is not what I need.

My html :

```
<table class="editor_listing_table ">
    <thead class="editor_listing_table_header">
    <tr>
        <th>
```

**UPDATED :**
If in css I have :

```
.editor_listing_table_header:first-child {
    background-color: olive !important; ;
}
// line below is commented :
/*.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(odd) {*/
/*    background-color: red !important;*/
/*}*/
```

What I see in the browser : https://prnt.sc/1spca6o

But if to uncomment line :

```
.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(odd)
...
```

Header is not olive as I expected : https://prnt.sc/1spcn7p

**UPDATED # 2 :**
I uploaded site on live site.
Please open page
http://hostels4j.my-demo-apps.tk/admin/facilities

In opened login page just click login - and open page
http://hostels4j.my-demo-apps.tk/admin/facilities
again

With all styles in my css file :

```
.editor_listing_table_header {
    @apply bg-gray-700 admin_block_border border-t-2 border-b-2;
}


.editor_listing_table_header {
    background-color: olive !important; ;
}
.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red !important;
}


.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(even) {
    /*background-color: #e8e8e8; !* light; *!*/
    background-color: #f1f1f1; /* 0aaf7e Green; */
}
```

I have 1st, 3rd rows in red(That is what I need.)
But I also have header rows in red(That is just what I do not need)

If to disable class editor_listing_table, then header has olive background : https://prnt.sc/1tgjl9p

- just what I expect

How to fix it ?

Comment: We need to see a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change your selector `.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(odd)` with `.editor_listing_table tbody tr:nth-child(odd)`, add tbody too so it can only add the colors to body rows and than if you want to add a different color to head, use thead selector for that

```
.editor_listing_table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #10eef9;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your header its own class and give it the right `background-color` that you want.

If the header is the first child of the parent that this option is also in place

```
parentName:first-child {
    background-color: #123456 // color you want
}
```

Comment: I triede and that does work

Comment: Add !important behind the css element just before the ; like background-color: #123456 !important;

Comment: I trie and it did not help. I did : 
    .editor_listing_table_header:first-child {
        background-color: olive !important; ;
    }

Comment: Isn’t it showing up on the inspector tool?

Comment: Pls take a look at UPDATED

Comment: Remove the :first-child psuodo element and see if it works

Comment: Just in the same block as in  UPDATED  block

Comment: Pls look at UPDATED 2 with live example

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, update your CSS with `:not(thead)` this might work

```
.editor_listing_table tr:nth-child(odd):not(thead) {
    background-color: #10eef9; 
}
```

The [`:not()` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) represents elements that do not match a list of selectors. It also prevents specific items from being selected. and here since you do not want one of the elements which is the header to be applied with the same CSS maybe you can use this solution to fix your issue.